# Python / NetworkX method to simplify networks

Tags: python, networkx

I want to simplify a network (networkX - DiGraph): Start-node is the red-node, end-nodes are the blue ones. There are also nodes at every point where two ore more branches split.
[image]

Every node/edge has different properties and based on that there are "rules" for merging branches. A basic rule is the following: If there is a node, which "splits into two branches", then the branch with the nearest node to that point will be merged into the other branch (in this example, node 2 is closer to the red node than node 1 - so branch "2" is merged into branch "1")
[image]

The result should be one branch with just serial nodes:

[image]

The first two steps would be the following: Merge the green node of the left branch into the right one. Second step: Merge end-node A of the left branch into the right one --> and so on

[image]

My question: how would you translate that method into networkX-code.
I thought about the following strategy: Search for the first "split" -- check which node at which branch is the nearest -- then merge that one + update the whole network. Are there build-in functions for that purpose?

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: have you succeeded in your search? i want to simplify my graph as well and would love some insights